# Migrating ArcGIS for Desktop script to ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-3

Recently I've been considering switching my department over to ArcGIS Pro in an effort to stay ahead in the ever-advancing world of GIS software.  Currently we run ArcGIS 10.3, and have many daily workflows automated using ArcPy and the Mapping Module specifically.  My question is...  What effect will switching to ArcGIS Pro have on our existing Python tools?  Will it run without any hitches if I try to run something that uses the ArcPy Mapping Module on an ArcGIS Pro map session?  Also, what are any other known considerations when switching to Pro?

This question came up in my mind when I started looking through the ArcPy reference for ArcGIS Pro and noticed that some basic functions that I use almost daily were not present (or at least that I could find) in the documentation.  For example, AddField_management()  is not in there.  Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking at (or not looking at?), but AddField is in both Pro and 10.3, thus its available in arcpy from either product.

Comment: Good to know.  Here is the reference I was looking at.  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/alphabetical-list-of-arcpy-classes.htm

Comment: That is the functions and classes part of the help. You'll want to look at the tool reference: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm

Comment: Although interesting, I've closed this as too broad because it is asking for a list of issues that may be encountered in such a migration. Asking about how to work with or around a single issue you have encountered or expect to encounter would represent focussed Q&A and be no problem to ask.

Comment: You can see an example of how I am trying to help answer your question, within the focussed Q&A format of GIS SE, rather than via collation of a list, at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173687/choosing-and-zooming-to-features-using-sql-query-in-arcpy-with-arcgis-pro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major difference that could affect all of your current scripts is that ArcGIS Pro's ArcPy module uses Python 3.x, which has many differences from 2.x.  For example, the simple `print` function from 2.x will not execute in 3.x because it has to use parenthesis.

There are many [other differences](http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2014/06/01/the-key-differences-between-python-2-7-x-and-python-3-x-with-examples/) that you will need to check depending on what you use in your code and some types such as `basestring` are not in 3.x.

That being said, if you're not using a lot of standard Python (i.e. just using `arcpy` tools), it may not affect you too much (other than certain functionality not being in Pro yet).  Otherwise, there are [tools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) available to port 2.x code to 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

There is a part of response in [ArcGISPro Faq](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/faq.htm)
The big difference is ArcGIS use Python 3.x and not Python 2.x. You need upgrade your script before use it in ArcGIS Pro

You can go to these link for more information:

- [Should I use Python 2 or Python 3 for my development activity?](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)
- [Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)