# Choosing and zooming to features using SQL query in ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, zoom, arcgis-pro

When using ArcPy with the ArcGIS 10.x architecture there is a simple coding pattern that I find I use frequently:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"ne_10m_admin_0_countries",df)[0]
lyr.definitionQuery = '"ADMIN" = ' + "'Chile'"
df.extent = lyr.getSelectedExtent()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

To see it in action:

1. Start ArcMap with a Blank map
2. Add a layer using a shapefile like ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp from Natural Earth
3. Copy/paste the code above into the Python window and you should see the country of Chile zoomed to

However, when I try to do something similar using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro what I find is:

1. Start ArcGIS Pro
2. Choose Map.aptx to open a map
3. Add a layer using a shapefile like ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp from Natural Earth
4. Copy/paste code like below into the Python pane

The definition query works great but then the [Map class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm) does not have a method available to perform a zoom to the extent of the features thus defined.

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
mapx = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
lyr = mapx.listLayers("ne_10m_admin_0_countries")[0]
lyr.definitionQuery = '"ADMIN" = ' + "'Chile'"
```

Is there a simple way to choose and zoom to features using an SQL query in ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?

As a workaround I've been investigating how to perhaps incorporate [Layout](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm) and [MapFrame](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/mapframe-class.htm) classes into my coding pattern and, although the latter has a `zoomToAllLayers` method that looks more hopeful, I have not yet been able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a way of doing this using the `Map class` either.

The code below works, but you're required to have a `Layout` and `Map Frame` present in your `Project`. It's strange that you can't do this in the Map view because you're able to right click on the layer in the Contents pane and click `Zoom to Layer`, but not through arcpy?

The zooming for the following code actually occurs on the Layout view, and not the Map view.

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
mapx = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
lyr = mapx.listLayers("ne_10m_admin_0_countries")[0]
lyr.definitionQuery = '"ADMIN" = ' + "'Chile'"

lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT')[0]

mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr, False, True))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an ArcGIS Idea to [Allow arcpy.mp to change the map extent in ArcGIS Pro](https://community.esri.com/ideas/15227-allow-arcpymp-to-change-the-map-extent-in-arcgis-pro):

> Currently in the latest version of [2.4.2], developers can only use
>   arcpy.mp to change the map extent in the  Map Frame but not in the Map
>   itself.
>
> Map Frame is an element of a layout, but for many projects there's no
>   need for a layout, as you may want only want to view the result map on
>   the screen and you don't really care about the layout of a printable
>   document.
>
> And there are many cases that you want to zoom the map to the selected
>   features and put focus on an particular area. To do this, logically
>   the user should be allowed to set the extent of the camera for the
>   specified 2D map. But this function is missing or not working.

Once that has been implemented it will address the requirement that led me to ask this question.  It is currently at a status of **In Product Plan** so hopefully it is not too far away.