# Zooming to point just added to feature class using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, zoom

I need to add zoom to a point in a feature class I just added it to. But I don't necessarily have a layout at this point.  I was able to do this in arcmap.

I looked like I could zoom to selected but no.
here is what I tried so far.

```
curMDX = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("d:\pathto aprx file")
def pantoselected(curMDX,SelectFC):
            inputstr = "same string that is in in Coordstr because I just added it to the FC"
            Expression = "{0} = '{1}'".format("Coordstr", inputstr)
            dataFrame = curMDX.listMaps()[0]
            lyr = dataFrame.listLayers(SelectFC)

            #  Works to here

            # by the way this works just fine in ArcMap 10.4
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
            zoomToAllLayers ({
```

Comment: I think an answer to this may be at https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/173687/115 but I don't have time to work on an answer at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

apparently there is no answer.  ESRI has decided that those kinds of features are only going to be available to developers that buy the SDK. That mean all of the users are SOL that need to simple things like zooming to a point.  On the other hand QGIS is free and this kind of tool is simple.

Comment: You can manually adjust the dataframe extent to center on your point and adjust the scale